# VBA Cells.Replace()

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

**SETUP**

I'm using VBA in Excel 2012

**QUESTION**

I need to search through a sheet and replace any "#"s. Only in the first column. The Second Cells.Replace does not work. I assume it is because "# # #" doesn't like that type of string.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
    'Find and replace "#" with ""
    Cells.Replace What:="###", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Cells.Replace What:="# # #", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Any Thing would.

Comment: If you are trying to replace any "#"s, why do you have `What:="###"`?

Comment: because there are a few comments that use #, and all the cells I want to replace are either ### or ## # # or # # #.

Comment: Then you are not trying to replace any "#"s.  Can you post some example data?

Comment: I've changed the code in my answer to work with the expanded requirements.

Comment: @mr.Reband I was trying to replace all the different combinations other than the single "#". I have since given up that dream. Too many combinations for it to handle that gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Erase Any Combination of #**

```
Cells.Replace "#", "", xlPart
```

** To Erase ### or ## # # or # # #**

```
Cells.Replace "###", "", xlPart
Cells.Replace "## # #", "", xlPart
Cells.Replace "# # #", "", xlPart
```

*Edit: Comment explains need to remove  ### or ## # # or # # #.*

Comment: I actually thought of that and tried it. The problem is that first off there is no set pattern. So i made a bunch of versions of that. The best way to do that would have been some version of a for loop. I actually just decided to use your first one, and replace all the "#"s with a " ".

Answer (score 1):

```
'Find and replace "#" with "" in the first column only
Columns(1).Cells.Replace What:="#", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should work. If it is not working as expected, be sure that you are specifying the same string. What looks like a space character may not be so either use your mid & char functions in Excel to double check or do a cut and paste directly from one of the cells you are looking for.